Prove that the point on one circle farthest from another circle must lie on the line connecting centers.
This question comes from a section in a text book about Lagrange Multipliers. The context of the question is such however, that it is clearly intended that the solution be based upon reasoning related to level curves. I mention this only to inform of why I am trying to solve it in the following way:
Question: Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be nonconcentric circles. Show that the point on $C_1$ farthest from $C_2$ must lie on the line through the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$.
My attempt:
Without loss of generality I will assume $C_2$ to be centered at the origin and of radius $R_{origin}$ and that $C_1$ is centered at $(a,b)$ and of radius $r$.
Now, consider the function F whose value is everywhere the distance of the general point $(x,y)$ from $C_2$. The level curves of this function form concentric circles around the origin, (because any given level curve is two concentric circles or a circle and a point or a single circle depending on the distance under consideration for that specific level curve).
So, as we move around $C_1$ we will find minima and maxima of F when we are moving parallel to one of these level curves.
So we seek to find the point $(x,y)$ on $C_1$ where the gradient is equal to that of an origin-centered circle of radius $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
For origin centered circles equation is $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and so $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{R^2-x^2}$ and for our purposes, for a general point $(x,y)$ on $C_1$, we want to have $x^2+y^2=R^2$ so that here we will be at a point on $C_1$ where the gradient is the same as that of a level curve.
Similarly for $C_1$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{r^2-(a-x)^2}}$
Ultimately this leads to me having to solve for $x$ the following:
$\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{r^2-(a-x)^2}}=\frac{2x}{b+\sqrt{r^2-(x-a)^2}}$
Which I'm not finding so easy to solve. The plan was that if I could solve for x and y then I would hope to show that gradient from $(a,b)$ to $(x,y)$ was same as that from origin to $(a,b)$ and that would solve the question.
Thanks for any help showing if there is an altogether better way or if I am making a mistake somewhere

I think you can establish this result more easily using a sketch and some simple geometry (cosine rule is what I would use, but other approaches may be possible). I can give a more complete answer if requested.

Euclid III.7: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII8.html

Thank you for your replies. I ought to add that the question is being asked in a context of learning to use Lagrange Multipliers and associated reasoning. It was my error to ask for alternative ways in the way that I did. I should have made it clear that such alternatives would still need to involve the use of Lagrange Multipliers or the concepts of Level Curves to solve the problem. Ultimately the goal is to get the student to master such methods, hence to requirement to use them to solve this problem.

You can choose the line joining the centres to be a co-ordinate axis

Yes! Thank you very much. This makes the solution almost trivial. This transformation can easily be seen to leave generality of the solution unaffected. Just as I assumed one circle to be centered at the origin so too I could have assumed the x-axis to run along the line joining the centers. Then, when the parallel-to-level-curves argument is made in this co-ordinate system, it leads to much simpler equations. Thank you very much for this insight.

The conclusion follows from thetriangle inequality and from the fact that every segment joining two points of the circle is shorter or equal to two times the radius.
